# Sockets in Android using Xamarin

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Android in Visual Studio 2013 and got the following problem:

When initializing a new Socket:

```
Socket _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

my app collapses.
It compiles without any problems and according to the output-log it is successfully installed on the device (Google Nexus 7 and Samsung Galaxy Tab), but it closes itself immediatly after opening.
I gave permission in the Android Manifest to the internet (and meanwhile to everything else).
This code line works without any problems in Xamarin Forms.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: What's your `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` value?

Comment: it is (will be) the 192.168.1.1
But it colllapses when initializing the socket, before I start connecting

Comment: Could you up your log cat? It should include `fatal exception` to help understand the reason

Comment: Thanks Neo for your help, but it turned out, I did made a mistake with the permissions. No idea what happened exactly, but now it works (with permissions for "Internet" and "Access_wifi_state")

Comment: Ah, congratulation ^^